# This animate I am using works, but is it correct?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So I am a new to Swift and taking lessons on YouTube and am piecing things together. For instance to move an SKSpriteNode back to its original position I have:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
     if let touch = touches.first {
         let location = touch.location(in: self)
         let touchedNodes = self.nodes(at: location)
         for node in touchedNodes.reversed() {
            if node.name == "draggable" {
            originalNode = touch.location(in: self)
            self.currentNode = node
             guard let scene = node.scene else { fatalError("Wait this node is not inside a scene!?") }
                        thePosition = node.convert(node.position, to: scene)
} } } }



func addMovement (obstacle:SKSpriteNode, origNP: CGPoint) {
        //  var actionArray = [SKAction]()
        let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: origNP.x, y: origNP.y), duration: 1.0)
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveAction])
        obstacle.run(sequence)
    }
```

The original code I found online had just one parameter (obstacle) and called this line:

```
let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: obstacle.position.x, y: obstacle.position.x.y), duration: 1.0)
```

I would just to know that the way I am doing it, is correct. Not a scenario where I am getting lucky and it will come back to bite me later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you are trying to achieve. The move action by itself seems ok.

You do NOT need to use a sequence for a single action though. A sequence is intended to be used for chaining multiple actions one after the other. Since you have just one action, you can update your code to:

```
    let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: origNP.x, y: origNP.y), duration: 1.0)
    obstacle.run(moveAction)
```

Comment: It's just a test app.  moving the SpriteNode back to it's original position in a smooth way.

Comment: @Caractacus Please see my updated answer, and mark it correct if it solves your problem.

Comment: I was doing two things before, and when I switched to one, I commented out that part just so I wouldn't forget the proper way.